# NestJS WebSocketGateway does not initialize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket, nestjs

According to the NestJS docs I've implemented the websockets gateway and providing it inside of the `AppModule`. The server is starting properly and I can serve static assets via http successfully. But I can't get the websockets running at all, the ws server is not available at `ws://localhost:3333` and the `afterInit` function is not executed at all. Even not when I am defining the `@SubscribeMessage`.

The gateway is implemented as

```js
@WebSocketGateway()
export class SocketGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
  afterInit() {
    console.log('Gateway initialized');
  }
}
```

The AppModule provides the gateway properly

```js
@Module({
  providers: [SocketGateway]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this is the bootstrap implementation

```js
export async function bootstrap() {
  let app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.listen(process.env.port || 3333, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

bootstrap();
```

My dependecies are

```
"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
"@nestjs/common": "5.5.0",
"@nestjs/core": "5.5.0",
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^6.1.0",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^6.1.0"
```

Maybe you see the problem directly. Thanks for your help, cheers!

Comment: You are mixing nest v5 and nest v6. Different major versions are not guaranteed to interoperate properly. Please update all your nest dependencies to v6, see https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide

Comment: This starts the gateway properly :) it is an nrwl/nx workspace including the 5.5.0 deps. Adding additional packages via npm installed 6.1.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your project, the major versions v5 and v6 of nest are mixed. Different major versions are not guaranteed to interoperate properly. Update all your dependencies to nest v6; you can have a look at the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide) for additional information about the update.

Run `$ npm i @nestjs/core@latest @nestjs/common@latest`

---

When you install new dependencies, watch out for peer dependency warnings from npm like this one:

```
npm WARN @nestjs/websockets@6.1.0 requires a peer of @nestjs/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: apparently this is also true for minors. In my case in different packages for nest I had ^9.0 and ^9.4. bumped all and it started :/

Comment: this was very time consuming stupid bug to fix, thank you!!!